# Converting Excel 2007 VBA to Excel 2003

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2003

I'm trying to adapt an xla add-in that I wrote for Excel 2007 to work in Excel 2003.  I have most of the issues sorted, but I'm having trouble finding a way to sort fields in a sheet.  I have rows of data which need to be sorted in order of creation date (the value of which is in column H).  Here's the Excel 2007 code I was using:

```
        'sort issues into descending order
        Sheets("In Progress").Sort.SortFields.Clear
        Sheets("In Progress").Sort.SortFields.Add _
                Key:=Range("H:H"), _
                SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                Order:=xlDescending, _
                DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        With Sheets("In Progress").Sort
            .SetRange Range("A2:M" & rowCount - 1)
            .Header = xlNo
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
```

Can anybody help me to get this to work with Excel 2003?

Comment: what error do you get? what doesn't work? did you try to remove step by step some lines of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to write the code in lower version so that it works in all versions.

I would use this code for sorting which will work in all versions.

```
With Sheets("In Progress")
    .Range("A2:M" & rowCount - 1).Sort Key1:=.Range("A2"), _
    Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo, _
    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
End With
```

Comment: Cheers, that seems to have done the trick!  Thanks very much.